# How can I stop Debian10 inside VirtualBox from loging me out when returning form screen lock

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, lock-screen

I have a Debian 10 inside a VirtualBox VM with the XFCE window manager.

Whenever I leave the VM Window unattended for some time, the screen lock engages and I'm asked for my password when returning to the session.

But once I supply my password, the screen blinks and I'm presented with another login prompt, this time with username AND password. After supplying both, I'm not returning to my previous session but I'm greeted by what seems to be a new X-session.

It worked before as expected. I did two things that might have caused the issue:

1. I dist-upgraded with apt and rebooted several times including a kernel update.
2. I switched the GraphicsController setting of the VM to "VBoxVGA" to make the automatic guest system resolution change work again (which stopped after a VirtualBox update, but does work again now).

How can I fix that issue?

Alternatively, as a workaround:

How do I disable screen lock?
The Settings Manager doesn't turn up anything for the search term "lock" and I can't find it in neither the Screen, Power or Display settings pane.

Comment: Google, xfce disable lock screen https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=xfce+disable+lock+screen

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself.

Turns out the VirtualBox Client Extensions are actually build against your current kernel headers.

If you update your kernel, you need to re-install (=re-build) the extensions, even if you did not change your VirtualBox version.

Problem solved afterwards.